# How to use PSTCollection for iOS5, in a subview?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, pstcollectionview

Currently I'm developing iOS app for iOS5, using storyboard. I have a view controller, in that view controller I have three views. I wan't my first view to use PSTCollection/UICollectionView but my iOS version is 5 so UICollectionView is out. How should I get to include a PSTCollectionView in the first view? I had tried to follow the example but I just doesn't get there at all. And the only example using storyboard: **CollectionView-Simple** unable to build because they are using UICollectionView.

Any idea? Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UICollectionView and PSTCollectionView are completely compatible, except that the class names are different. Do a find and replace on class names, and nearly all UICollectionView examples will work.

Comment: But do I create colletionView in InterfaceBuilder? Or create a view associated to a class inherits PSTCollectionView? I don't know how or where to start..

Comment: There are lots of good UICollectionView examples. There is no need for me to create another here. PSTCollectionView works the same, but generally cannot be used with a NIB or Storyboard.

Comment: I tried some of the example but it doesn't quite suit my case.
In my case, I have already a UIViewController containing UIScrollView, and in the UIScrollView I have Three Views. I need to transform the first view into PSUICollectionView. Is there any example that cross your mind when you feel it is a good example for me?

Comment: Having other views is not relevant to adding a UICollectionView. A quick search found [this tutorial](http://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2012/09/a-simple-uicollectionview-tutorial/) which shows all the steps necessary.

Comment: One more thing out of curiosity, pstcollectionview comes with example with storyboard. like "FlowLayoutHorizontal", "CollectionView-Simple" but why all of them failed to build?

Comment: To be honest, I've never looked at the provided examples from PSTCollectionView. I've only ever taken a UICollectionView that I liked in iOS 6 and adapted it to be a PSTCollectionView so it worked in iOS 5. Especially now, when so few iOS 5 devices are left in the wild, the justification to use PSTCollectionView is becoming harder to find.